# UrbanAirship Push Messages not arriving to Android app unless I restart the device

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I'm testing my Android app in dev environment with UrbanAirship as push notifications provider. Sometimes after sending several pushes (let's say I receive 3 or 4), they just stop arriving I don't know what happens with the other pushes I sent (5 or 6 more).

I send all pushes via console, not using Urban Airship web forms for testing pushes.

I've tried closing the app and reopening it and nothing happens. Just when I restart my device then all the pending messages arrive at once.

Could you please tell me how to avoid this?